# OpenCV Out of memory error

Tags: python, opencv

I working on a video composition project using multiple user generated videos . Below is my code

```
df=pd.concat(user,axis=1)
#print df

dfs= df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['Panning','sec'])]


video_index=0
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(videoList[0])

fra=[]
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("Output.avi", fourcc, fps, (width, height), True)
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    fra.append(frame)

    for index,row in dfs.iterrows():
          if (row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning').any():
               idx = row[:, 'Panning'][row[:, 'Panning'] == 'Panning'].index.tolist()
               sec = int(row.loc[(idx, 'sec')].values.tolist()[0])
               if cap.get(0)==1000*sec:
                  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoList[indices.index(random.choice(idx))])
                  cap.set(0, sec * 1000)
                  ret, frame = cap.read()
                  fra.append(frame)
          else:

              ret,frame=cap.read()
              fra.append(frame)
              if frame is None:
                  video_index += 1
                  if video_index == len(videoList):
                      break
                  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoList[indices.index(long_dur())])

                  cap.set(0,1000*sec)
                  ret, frame = cap.read()
                  fra.append(frame)
```

When I am trying to run I am getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The numpy array of typenum=2, ndims=3 can not be created) in NumpyAllocator::allocate, file ..\..\..\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp, line 184
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/chaitanya/PycharmProjects/Thesis/ROI.py", line 86, in <module>
    ret,frame=cap.read()
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes in function cv::OutOfMemoryError
```

I am not able to understand the problem. I need help on this error

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

You are continuously appending your frames to the fra array. Sooner or later you are going to finish your RAM this way and that's what happened.